# Access view from Fragment A in Fragment B

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

Im trying to access a Textview from Fragment A in Fragment B to change the text, im getting a null pointer. ive tried the following.

`public void setText(String text) {
        TextView t = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_menu); 
        t.setText(text);
    }`

i have also tried

```
 test = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.message_menu);
 test.setText("bla bla");
```

I have tried inflating another view too

```
View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
test = (TextView) test..findViewById(R.id.message_menu);
```

Tried using a NewInstance with the following code in Fragment B

```
test = (TextView) FragmentLogin.newInstance().getView().findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);
test.setText("hello testing ");
```

And Fragment A :

```
 public static FragmentBottomMenu newInstance() {
    FragmentBottomMenu fragment = new FragmentBottomMenu();
    return fragment;
}
```

still getting a null pointer exception.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Don't do this, it's just bad practice. Notify the activity of whatever event is causing the text change, and let the activity call some public method on the second fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code examples are pointing to the View of the **current** Fragment! To properly access the other Fragment's View, use this:

```
text = (TextView) [otherFragmentInstance].getView().findViewById(R.id.message_menu);
text.setText("bla bla");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer i tried your solution but stil getting a null exception. i have updated my question, which shows the code i tried.. Thanks